# Why is there a discrepancy between sources about atoms' sizes?

Tags: atomic-physics

The internet presents many different values for distinct atoms' sizes.

For example, [this site](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zp3dh39/revision/4) claims that a hydrogen atom is $\rm 2.5×10^{-11}\  m$ , [that site](http://www.astronoo.com/en/articles/size-of-atoms.html) says it's $\rm 53×10^{-12} \ m$, and yet [another site](https://www.sizes.com/natural/atoms.htm) gives a number of $\rm 37×10^{-12}\  m$. The figures for other atoms also vary wildly in the same manner.

Why is it so? Is there a consensus on atom sizes as of now, or is it still a matter of debate? If it's the latter case, could you point me to a meta-source that simply takes the averages of all the proposed numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, because of quantum mechanics, there is not a sharply defined size of a hydrogen atom. The wavefunction of the electron orbiting the nuclueus falls off smoothly but is non-zero at arbitrarily large distances from the nucleus. This means, there is some extremely small but finite probability to find the electron orbiting a proton very far away. The usual quantity people refer to as the size is the [Bohr radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius), which is a characteristic length scale defining a region where the electron is most likely to be.

Second, you want to look for authoratitative sources, not random links on the internet. The [particle data group](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-phys-constants.pdf) gives the Bohr radius to many decimal places including the experimental uncertainty; the first few digits are $5.3 \times 10^{-11}\ {\rm m}$. They even give you a formula so you can plug numbers in and check this for yourself.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. What is the authoritative source for the sizes of other elements?

Comment: @longtry Actually [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius#Empirically_measured_atomic_radius) is usually a good start, especially because they often [link to their sources](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1725697). It looks like this table gives the size of Hydrogen as 25 pm. Note this table is using the covalent radius, not the Bohr radius. The article also has [a section of different definitions of atomic radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius#Definitions). I am not a chemist, so unfortunately my knowledge doesn't go much deeper than the Bohr radius of H.

Comment: Here's another wikipedia page with more data and more references to dig into: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radii_of_the_elements_(data_page)